# Enter UEFI Setup on Lenovo G580

Tags: windows, boot, bios, uefi

I have a Lenovo G580 laptop and I attempted to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. However, I later decided to uninstall Ubuntu. While trying to restore the Windows boot loader, I encountered an issue where I was unable to escape the Boot Menu screen at startup (I deleted the bootloader). At that point, I was unable to access the UEFI Setup. Ultimately, I had to reinstall Windows and format the disk.

I attempted several methods to enter the UEFI Setup, including

- pressing the F2 key and Fn+F2 before turning on the laptop,
- trying to enter through the Novo Menu - Windows will start, or Boot Menu opens if bootloader not present
- accessing it via the Windows 10 recovery environment (opens the boot menu)
- disconnected all peripherals
- tried resetting the UEFI Setup twice by disconnecting the battery and hard disk and pressing the power button for 30 seconds
- attempted to boot the notebook without the hard drive

I was only able to access the system or Boot Menu and could not proceed further.

Under no circumstances does "Press Enter for startup options" appear when starting the notebook.

Comment: @Peregrino69 windows will start (or the boot menu will open if the bootloader is not present).

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777568/edit) your question instead to provide new info. This way the question gets more focused and everything relevant is immediately available. I added this so you can delete the comment. Comments aren't for discussion but for others to ask for clarifications, suggest actions etc... so the open comment space is a bit limited. Please verify my edit and correct if I accidentally changed the intention.

Answer (score 1):

For Lenovo:   Start up and let run.  Restart (not shut down).  This slows down Fast Startup.  Watch the startup carefully at the bottom:   "Press Enter for startup options".

That works on all my Lenovo Laptops and all customer Lenovo laptops and should work here.